# What is a monad for someone who doesn't want to learn Haskell in order to understand it?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

What is a monad in programming, and can it be explained such that:

1. You don't need any prior knowledge of Haskell to understand.
2. You can go ahead and use or build the concept in more mainstream programming languages such as C++/Java/Scala.

Basically, I've been coming across this term in my online learning. As an example, this Java 8 Stream tutorial mentions monads (http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/). So I would like to understand the fundamental concept in a useful way. (As opposed to a stupid way like "Imagine programming as an orange, then monads would be grapefruit ..." sort of thing.)

However, each monad tutorial seems to require prior knowledge of (or tries to teach you on-the-fly) Haskell or Haskell syntax.

Comment: There is not much advanced Haskell involved in most articles about monads anyway. You can see it as an abstraction of continuations.

Comment: A monad basically comes down to the fact that you have a higher oder type `m`, such that you can do `(a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`, so you have a function that takes as input `a`s, and returns an `m b` for that, then you have an `m a`, and that returns an `m b`. You can for instance define a list monad, or a `Maybe` monad, etc.

Comment: The thing is, most programming languages don't have a sufficiently powerful type system to really express the idea of monads, namely, they don't support higher-kinded polymorphism. So, for explaining monads, a quick intro to Haskell syntax is the easiest way. The alternative is to introduce it without any programming language at all, using only math syntax – but that doesn't make it easier for most non-Haskell programmers either. — Mind, you can certainly translate _any given monad_ to, say, C++, but that obscures the fundamental idea behind the concept.

Comment: The problem, as leftroundabout pointed out, is that for a long time, Haskell was the "most mainstream" language that was actually capable of expressing what a monad is. Neither Java's nor C++'s type system can actually express monads, so it is impossible to explain them using those language. Only recently has Scala come into existence, which is actually powerful enough to express monads, however, its syntax for doing so is much less elegant than Haskell's. (And honestly: the tricky part to understand are the semantics of monads, the syntax needed to explain that is tiny.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag You said " the tricky part to understand are the semantics of monads, the syntax needed to explain that is tiny". Brilliant! So can someone explain the semantics without using incomprehensible Haskell syntax? For example, I can explain the concept of a class without writing code in any particular language. Or I might use an invented, simplified language or pseudocode. I don't need to write a C++ header and implementation to explain it.

Comment: I found the blog post [Overloading Semicolon, or, monads from 10,000 Feet](https://blog.osteele.com/2007/12/overloading-semicolon/) very helpful. Anyway, monads are such an extremely generalized concept that it will take you a while to understand all its applications. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: The problem in explaining what a monad is, is similar to the problem of explaining something simple but completely new to someone. If you once tried to explain to a child what are numbers, then you understand this. It seems to you that the numbers are very simple and the obvious thing. But the child needs time, so that his brain can understand this abstraction. The same with monads. In fact, they are not more complicated than numbers, but their idea for you is new. Therefore, explain that it is so hard.

Comment: I think this is the wrong question to ask. You're not going to be happy with any answer you get, because the form of the question sets up monads as a big, complicated, scary topic. When people come back with incredibly simple answers you're going to reject them because they don't fit your preconceptions.

Comment: Wikipedia has one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition

Comment: @dfeuer the wikipedia article is pretty.... inaccessible. I think [this](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) is a pretty good explanation in pictures.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I wasn't being very serious. For a good category-theoretic explanation, you'd be much better off with the Catsters video lectures or an explanation by Bartosz Milewski.

Comment: @dfeuer sorry missed the sarcasm, perhaps because my brain was preoccupied with how this obvious dupe got upvotes and an answer...

Comment: As I understand it, you think that not the knowledge of Haskell does not let you understand what a monad is. But I assure you that if you knew the syntax and semantics of Haskell, this does not mean that you would immediately understand this concept. The problem with monads is wider.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to try and give the simplest possible explanation using Scala syntax and semantics.

A Monad is *any* type that has the following signature:

```
trait Monad[A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A ⇒ Monad[B]): Monad[B]
}

def unit[A](x: A): Monad[A]
```

and satisfies the following laws:

- *Left Identity*:

  ```
  unit(x).flatMap(f) == f(x)
  ```
- *Right Identity*:

  ```
  m.flatMap(unit _) == m
  ```
- *Associativity*:

  ```
  m.flatMap(f).flatMap(g) == m.flatMap(f(_).flatMap(g))
  ```

*And that's it*. That is the beauty of monads. *Anything* that satisfies those constraints is a monad. And there are lots of things that satisfy those constraints: Lists, Sets, Dictionaries, Maps, Options, Database Queries, Continuations, Errors, Side Effects, Interpreters, Compilers, …

The power of monads comes from the combination of *just enough* structure that you can write lots of operations that operate on monads, and at the same time *so little* structure that lots of things are monads. The combination of those two properties means that you can write lots of operations *once* that then apply to lots of different types of objects.

And that's one of the problems with monads: their generality. A monad is a very general abstraction, that makes it not immediately obvious what it is. I mean, what do sets, lists, database queries, side effects, continuations, and compilers have in common?

Comment: I'm upvoting this, almost against my better judgement. It does a great job of explaining *why it's hard to explain monads*, but should really be an answer on the linked dupe.

Answer (score 4):

To take it to C++ (prior to [metaclasses](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/), which will eventually give a way to express this properly), the best description of a monad is this:

- A *parameterised class* (like the STL container types), i.e. a class of the form

  ```cpp
  template <typename a>
  class M;
  ```
- which supports at least the following functions:

  - “Trivial injection”

    ```cpp
    template <typename a, typename b>
    M<a> pure (a x);
    ```

    <sup>Mathematicians call this *η*, Haskell has traditionally called it `return`, other languages often `unit`.</sup>
  - Functor<sup>†</sup> mapping

    ```cpp
    template <typename a, typename b>
    M<b> fmap (std::function<b(a)> f, M<a> m);
    ```
  - A flattening operation

    ```cpp
    template <typename a, typename b>
    M<a> join (M< M<a> > mm);
    ```

    <sup>Which mathematicians call *μ*. Many programming languages (including Haskell) don't implemented this by itself but combined with `fmap`, as such it is then called `flatMap` or `>>=`. But `join` is the simplest form.</sup>
- such that the [monad laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition) are fulfilled.

Example for an array type:

```cpp
template <typename a>
struct array {
  std::vector<a> contents;
};

template <typename a>
array<a> pure(a x) {
  return array<a>{{std::vector<a>({x})}};   // array with only a single element.
}

template <typename a, typename b>
array<b> fmap(std::function<b(a)> f, array<a> m) {
  std::vector<b> resultv;
  for(auto& x: m) {
    resultv.push_back(f(x));
  }
  return array<b>{{resultv}};   // array with the elements transformed by the given function
}

template <typename a>
array<a> join(array< array<a> > mm) {
  std::vector<a> resultv;

  for(auto& row: mm.contents) {
    for(auto& x: row.contents) {
      resultv.push_back(x);
    }
  }
  return array<a>{{resultv}};   // array with all the rows concatenated.
}
```

So, what's the use of this? Well, `fmap` is pretty useful on its own right, when you quickly want to map a lambda over all the elements of an array (allowing for changing type), without having to fiddle with any iterators (unlike `std::transform`). But `fmap` doesn't really require a monad.

What monads really shine at is *generically sequencing actions*. That won't become very clear with that array example, so let me introduce another monad:

```cpp
template <typename a>
struct writer {
  std::string logbook;
  a result;
};

template <typename a, typename b>
writer<a> pure (a x) {
  return writer<a>{{"", x}};  // nothing to log yet
}

template <typename a, typename b>
writer<b> fmap (std::function<b(a)> f, writer<a> m){
  return writer<b>{{m.logbook, f(m.result)}};
                      // simply keep the log as-is
}

template <typename a, typename b>
writer<a> join (writer< writer<a> > mm) {
  return writer<a>{{mm.logbook + mm.result.logbook, m.result.result}};
      // Concatenate the two logs, and keep the inner value
}
```

`writer` more resembles the most [in]famous Haskell monad, `IO`. The `writer` type allows you to compose arbitrary log-writing functions together, and without ever having to worry about it, gather all the logbook information.

You may wonder at this point: what *is* there to log? None of the operations above actually produce any logbook entries! Indeed they don't – in fact the monad laws would be violated if they did! Monads are not about particular actions, pre-built values. Rather, they just give you an extremely generic *framework* for “glueing together” such actions.

A simple example of such a glueing-compositor is `replicateM`, which takes a single monadic action and executes it *n* times in sequence, gathering all the results. Unfortunately, this can't be properly typed in C++ in full generality, but here's a specialized version that only works for the writer monad. First, let's quickly implement that combined fmap-join I mentioned earlier, because it's much more handy than `join` in practice:

```cpp
template<typename a, typename b>
writer<b> flatMap(std::function<writer<b>(a)> f, writer<a> xs) {
  return join(fmap(f,xs));
}

template <typename a>
writer<array<a>> replicateM (int n, writer<a> m) {
  if (n>0) {
    writer<array<a>> resultv = fmap(pure, m);
    for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {
      resultv = flatMap( [&](array<a> xs){
                           return fmap( [&](a x){
                                           return xs.push_back(x);}
                                      , m );}
                       , resultv);
    }
  } else {
    return pure(std::vector<a>());
  }
}
```

Notice that none of the code above actually uses anything specific to `writer`, so I could copy&paste it and use it for any other monad. (Or, use a language with higher-kinded polymorphism and just write it once and for all.)

What `replicateM` does in case of `writer` is frankly quite dumb – it just repeats the same log message `n` times, and replicates the result value `n` times as well. However, that's just the simplest example: monads can also have much more functionality, for example, in the IO monad, each invocation might yield a different result (e.g. because it reads from standard input). A generic monad interface allows you to abstract over all kinds of different side-effects, but still keeps clear track of what side-effects can possibly happen in a given context.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Unfortunately, the C++ community misuses the word “functor” simply to describe *function objects*. Although this is a related concept, a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) is actually more than that.</sub>

Comment: You could write a generic `replicateM` with higher-kinded polymorphism (a template template parameter): `template<template<typename> class M, typename A> M<array<A>> replicateM(int n, M<A> m)`, but you’d need to reorganise a few things—for example, `pure` would need to be a static member function on each monad so you could refer to `M::pure` generically, otherwise the overloads of `template<typename A> writer<A> pure(A)` and `template<typename A> array<A> pure(A)` are ambiguous because they differ only by return type. It’s much easier to express this concept in languages that were made for it!